# Why do we need to use .setLink() when sharing on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

Does anybody now why we need the `.setLink()` method for the FaceBook dialog `ShareDialogBuilder` when displaying posts on users `FB wall` from app ?

If I remove or set to null the other parameters are not posted i.e. Description, image etc.

When users clicks post on FB they are navigated to link (which by default is https://developers.facebook.com/android).

I have no use for this but can't seem to not include it.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(LogDive.this)
.setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
.setRequestCode(4)
.setApplicationName("Dive App")
.setName("Dive App- Dive Site....."+diveSiteString)
.setDescription(bottomDiveTime+ " minute dive at "+ waterTemperature +
" degrees celcuis, vizibilty "+viz+ " meters. Depth:  "
+diveDepth+" meters. Dive Rating: "+diveRate+"/5!")
.setPlace(diveLoctionString)
.setPicture("https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJm5R.jpg?s=128&g=1")
.build();
```

Comment: Maybe something to do with the app still in devolper mode?